# JQuery UI DatePicker extend

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to extend the datepicker with some HTML data:

```
<div class=“datepicker” data-maxDate="+1m +1w" data-prevText=“Earlier”></div>
```

This really be like this markup :

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: "+1m +1w", prevText: "Earlier" });
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the quotes in your HTML. Change `“` to `"`

```
<div class="datepicker" data-maxDate="+1m +1w" data-prevText="Earlier"> </div>
```

Use jQuery `attr()`

```
var date = $(".datepicker");

date.datepicker({
    maxDate: date.attr('data-maxDate'),
    prevText: date.attr('data-prevText')
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tUBLm/2/)**

or **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

```
var date = $(".datepicker");

date.datepicker({
    maxDate: date.data('maxdate'),
    prevText: date.data('prevtext')
});
```

Comment: is this a JQUERY Ui extension or just in the default Jquery?

Comment: Included in Default jQuery. But for Datepicker you need jQuery UI